# Why if $B = \{x : |x+1| ≤ 3 \}$ then $B$ equals $[ -4, \infty )$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I really don't understand why $B$ is from $-4$ to infinity because

$x+1 ≤ 3$

$x ≤ 2$

and

$-3 ≤ x+1$

$-4 ≤ x$

Shouldn't it be $B = [-4, 2]$?

Comment: It is certainly not $[-4,\infty)$, for example for $x = 10$ we have that $|x+1| = |11| = 11 \nleqq 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not. $$|x+1|\leq 3 \iff -3 \leq x+1 \leq 3 \iff -4 \leq x \leq 2,$$ so the interval is $[-4,2]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I delete this post then?

Comment: There's no need. Everyone has these kind of doubts one time or another. And you can't delete the question once there is at least an answer given. The best you can do is to accept the answer that helped the most and carry on. Good studies :)

Answer (score 3):

for $x\geq -1$ we get $x+1\le3$ this is equivalent to $x\le 2$
or
$$x<-1$$ we have $$-x-1\le 3$$ this is equivalent to $$x\geq -4$$
therefore we have $$-4\le x\le 2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I delete this post then?

Comment: @sambo14 No. and if he answered your question you should accept his answer. and an up vote is also nice!